# In which way is Angular Focus Manager WAI-ARIA compatible?

Tags: angularjs, focusmanager

Someone please explain `ARIA compatibility of Angular Focus Manager` that is mentioned on [this](https://github.com/obogo/angular-focusmanager) `Github` page.

Answer (score 0):

answer is on the page itself.

Have you ever tried navigating through a web application using the TAB key? You have probably found the results to be less than desirable. The browser treats all elements as if it were a single web page, including your application. Angular Focus Manager fixes this limitation of the browser by allowing you to organize your application into focus groups. Focus groups organize elements into sections maintaining the focus index on a more granular level.

Comment: Yes, I can see ist and it works great. I am a bit confused about the use of tabindex="-1" inside "focus-groups"